# Delphi. What is "DAX Error"? And how it may be related to INI file writing?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, com, ini

I got "DAX Error", "Unable to write to [path].INI file" for e Delphi COM (exe) Server in production. 
[image: DAX Error on INI File]

I searched and investigated a lot but didn't find any clear, concrete answer on 1st question:
What is **DAX Error**!?

2nd part: 
Error is related to write-action into INI file.
I found that whenever it is working with INI file within our legacy application, it's used `TiniFile` class - encapsulator for INI-files WinAPIs.
Error message `Unable to write to %s` may be generated from this Delphi native code:

```
procedure TIniFile.WriteString(const Section, Ident, Value: string);
begin
  if not WritePrivateProfileString(PChar(Section), PChar(Ident),
                                   PChar(Value), PChar(FFileName)) then
    raise EIniFileException.CreateResFmt(@SIniFileWriteError, [FileName]);
end;
```

Some custom methods that operate on INI file are invoked via **DCOM** and in Windows system events DCOM error were observed for that period of time (only print screen, original events were lost).
Also the same INI file is read/changed from C# shared DLL loaded into some windows/web-services.

Usually it works, but only in one case operator saw that application is frozen and these messages appeared.

**Question2:**
What may be cause of INI file writing failure?
May it be DCOM configuration (access rights?) or something else might cause this too?

---

OS: Windows Server 2003
Delphi7
INI file is not mapped in registry

I am thinking that problem shouldn't appear nor because of `WriteString` is invoked from multiple threads, since `WritePrivateProfileString` itself Locks/Unlocks file when writing (if believing to SysInternals Process Monitor), nor because file itself was read-only (it's not possible during night to change attribute for several seconds).
Any ideas, hint, links are welcome.

Comment: Put madExcept in the process and get a stack trace

Comment: DAX is Delphi ActiveX and madExcept maybe won't help in this case

Comment: GUYS who down-voted, PLEASE EXPLAIN ME WHY!???
Just for me.. for future.. to know what i put wrong!

Comment: @SirRufo, +1 for > "DAX is Delphi ActiveX", need more proofs :)  

----
Once upon a time I played with madExcept, ans as far as I remember not so much capabilities to catch ActiveX exceptions (maybe I am wrong). madExcept has other "feature" - it's not free :)  

-----
Our legacy application has it own exception tracing mechanism (hook on kernel), unfortunately it wasn't enabled. 
-----
Anyway, thanks for suggestions.